# How to increase Cart Count of action bar Textview from Recyclerview Adapter

Tags: android

Hi I have MainActivity which has ActionBar, and In Action Bar I Have CartIcon with textview. When i add from fragment i want to increase Textview of Action Bar. But i couldn't do this. Below is my code:
My Badge XML Here

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="48dp"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="right" >

<!-- Menu Item Image -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cart"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_shopping_cart_black_24dp" />

<!-- Badge Count -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_notifcation_textview"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:text="99"
    android:background="@drawable/icon_background"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

MainActivity Code Here.

```
package pk.com.sabsons.sabsons.activity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import pk.com.sabsons.sabsons.R;
import pk.com.sabsons.sabsons.database.DBHelper;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity   {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TextView count;
protected DBHelper mDBHelper;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mDBHelper = new DBHelper(MainActivity.this);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    count = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.actionbar_notifcation_textview);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);



}
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new OphthalmicFragment(), "Ophthalmic");
    adapter.addFragment(new ContactFragment(), "Contact");
    adapter.addFragment(new LenseCareFragment(), "Lens Care");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setSaveFromParentEnabled(false);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.badge);
    MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, R.layout.badger_menu);
    RelativeLayout notifCount = (RelativeLayout)   MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    TextView tv = (TextView) notifCount.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_notifcation_textview);
    ImageView img = notifCount.findViewById(R.id.cart);

    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cartActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CartActivity.class);
            startActivity(cartActivity);
        }
    });
    String count = String.valueOf(mDBHelper.numberOfRows());
    tv.setText(count);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Cart Icon is Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.badge:
            // User chose the "Settings" item, show the app settings UI...
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Its Working in OptionItemSlected here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.cart:
            // User chose the "Settings" item, show the app settings UI...
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Its Working in OptionItemSlected here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;



        default:
            // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
            // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }



}

public void myFunction(){

}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

}

and My Fragment Code is this.

```
package pk.com.sabsons.sabsons.activity;


public class OphthalmicFragment extends Fragment implements RvAdapter.AdapterCallBack {

View view;
private List<Ophthamic> lstOphthalmic;
private RecyclerView myrv;
private RvAdapter recyleradpater;
//https://awsrh.blogspot.com/2018/03/volley-glide-tutorial-parse-json.html
// private String URL_JSON = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aws1994/f583d54e5af8e56173492d3f60dd5ebf/raw/c7796ba51d5a0d37fc756cf0fd14e54434c547bc/anime.json";
private String URL_JSON = "http://sabsoft.com.pk/Opticals/texting?category='Ophthalmic Lens'";
private JsonArrayRequest ArrayRequest;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private ProgressDialog dialog;

public OphthalmicFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    lstOphthalmic = new ArrayList<>();
    jsoncall();


}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myrv = view.findViewById(R.id.rv);
    recyleradpater = new RvAdapter(getContext(), lstOphthalmic,this);
    myrv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    myrv.setAdapter(recyleradpater);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ophthalmic, container, false);

}


public void jsoncall() {


    ArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL_JSON, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {


            JSONObject jsonObject = null;


            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(i),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                try {

                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    Ophthamic anime = new Ophthamic();
                    anime.setId(jsonObject.getString("id"));
                    anime.setItemCode(jsonObject.getString("code"));
                    anime.setCategorie(jsonObject.getString("category"));
                    anime.setAdditional(jsonObject.getString("additional"));
                    anime.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                    anime.setDescription(jsonObject.getString("description"));
                    anime.setImage(jsonObject.getString("image"));
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,anime.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    lstOphthalmic.add(anime);


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                recyleradpater.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }






        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error" + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(ArrayRequest);
}

private synchronized void showDialog(String title) {

    if (dialog != null && !dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.setTitle(title);
        dialog.show();
    }
}

private synchronized void dismissDialog() {

    if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}


@Override
public void onChangeBadgeCount() {

}
}
```

and My Adpater code is here.

```
package pk.com.sabsons.sabsons.adapter;

public class RvAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RvAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
RequestOptions options ;
private Context mContext ;
private List<Ophthamic> mData ;
private Dialog myDialogue;
private DBHelper mDBHelper;
private AlertDialog.Builder builder;


public RvAdapter(Context mContext, List lst, AdapterCallBack adpatercallback) {


    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mData = lst;
    options = new RequestOptions()
            .centerCrop()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
            .error(R.drawable.loading);
    adpatercallback = adpatercallback;


}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view ;
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.opthalmic_item_row,parent,false);
    // click listener here
    final MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    myDialogue = new Dialog(mContext);
    myDialogue.setContentView(R.layout.dialogue_box);

    myDialogue.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    viewHolder.view_container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(mContext, DetailsActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("id",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getId());
            i.putExtra("code",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getItemCode());
            i.putExtra("name",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getName());
            i.putExtra("additional",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getAdditional());
            i.putExtra("description",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getDescription());
            i.putExtra("image",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getImage());
            mContext.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    viewHolder.addcart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Initialize Dialogue Controls
            final EditText qty,sph,cyl,addl;
            Button qtyadd,qtysub,sphadd,sphsub,cyladd,cylsub,addladd,addlsub;
            qtyadd = myDialogue.findViewById(R.id.qtyadd);
            qtysub = myDialogue.findViewById(R.id.qtysub);
            sphadd = myDialogue.findViewById(R.id.sphadd);
            sphsub = myDialogue.findViewById(R.id.sphsub);
            cyladd = myDialogue.findViewById(R.id.cyladd);
            cylsub = myDialogue.findViewById(R.id.cylsub);
            addladd = myDialogue.findViewById(R.id.addladd);
            addlsub = myDialogue.findViewById(R.id.addlsub);
            qty = myDialogue.findViewById(R.id.qty);
            sph = myDialogue.findViewById(R.id.sph);
            cyl = myDialogue.findViewById(R.id.cyl);
            addl = myDialogue.findViewById(R.id.addl);
            TextView dialogue_name = myDialogue.findViewById(R.id.prod_name);
            TextView dialogue_category = myDialogue.findViewById(R.id.prod_category);
            Button save = myDialogue.findViewById(R.id.btnsave);
            Button cancel = myDialogue.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
            ImageView img = myDialogue.findViewById(R.id.img);

            //Hiding Or Showing Additional Layout
            LinearLayout addlLayout = myDialogue.findViewById(R.id.addlLayout);
            if(mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getAdditional().equals("0")){
                addlLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }else{
                addlLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            //Setting Dialogue Controls
            dialogue_name.setText(mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getName());
            dialogue_category.setText(mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getCategorie());
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.uvs_logo);
            myDialogue.show();

            save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String code = mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getItemCode();
                    String name = mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getName();
                    String category = mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getCategorie();
                    String itemqty = qty.getText().toString() ;
                    String totalqty = "0" ;
                    String rp = "0" ;
                    String totalamount = "0" ;
                    String itemcyl = cyl.getText().toString();
                    String itemsph = sph.getText().toString();
                    String itemaddl = addl.getText().toString();
                    String itemcolor = "0";
                    if(mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getAdditional().equals("0")){
                        itemaddl = "none";
                        itemcolor = "none";
                    }
                    String image = mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getImage();
                    mDBHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);

                    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

                    Date d=new Date();
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
                    String currentDateTimeString = sdf.format(d);

                    try{
                   boolean result =  mDBHelper.insertOrder(code,name,itemqty,totalqty,rp,totalamount,category,itemcyl,itemsph,itemaddl,itemcolor,image);

                   if(result == true) {

                       builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                       builder.setTitle("Database Status")
                               .setMessage("Data Inserted")
                               .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                       myDialogue.dismiss();

                                   }
                               })
                               .setIcon(R.drawable.uvs_logo)
                               .show();
                   }else{
                       Toast.makeText(mContext, "Insert Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
                    }catch (Exception e){

                        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                        builder.setTitle("Error")
                        .setMessage(e.getMessage())
                                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        myDialogue.dismiss();

                                    }
                                })
                                .show();


                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Failed"+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }



                }
            });

            cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    myDialogue.dismiss();
                }
            });

            qtyadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Integer quantity = Integer.valueOf(qty.getText().toString());
                    quantity = quantity +1;
                    qty.setText(quantity.toString());
                }
            });

            qtysub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Integer quantity = Integer.valueOf(qty.getText().toString());
                    if(quantity > 1){
                        quantity = quantity - 1;

                    }else{
                        quantity = 1;
                    }
                    qty.setText(quantity.toString());
                }
            });

            sphadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Double spherical = Double.valueOf(sph.getText().toString());
                    spherical = spherical + 0.25;
                    sph.setText(spherical.toString());
                }
            });

            sphsub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Double spherical = Double.valueOf(sph.getText().toString());
                    spherical = spherical - 0.25;
                    sph.setText(spherical.toString());
                }
            });
            cyladd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Double spherical = Double.valueOf(sph.getText().toString());
                    if(spherical >= 0.0){
                        Double cylinder = Double.valueOf(cyl.getText().toString());
                        if(cylinder > 0.0){
                            cylinder = 0.0;
                            cyl.setText(cylinder.toString());
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Inside grater than 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else if(cylinder < 0.0){

                            cylinder = cylinder + 0.25;
                            cyl.setText(cylinder.toString());

                        }

                    }else if(spherical <= 0.0) {
                        Double cylinder = Double.valueOf(cyl.getText().toString());
                        cylinder = cylinder + 0.25;
                        cyl.setText(cylinder.toString());

                    }

                }
            });
            cylsub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Double spherical = Double.valueOf(sph.getText().toString());
                    if(spherical <0.0){
                        Double cylinder = Double.valueOf(cyl.getText().toString());
                        if(cylinder != 0.0){
                            cylinder = cylinder - 0.25;
                            cyl.setText(cylinder.toString());
                        }

                    }else {
                        Double cylinder = Double.valueOf(cyl.getText().toString());
                        cylinder = cylinder - 0.25;
                        cyl.setText(cylinder.toString());
                    }

                }
            });
            addladd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Double additional = Double.valueOf(addl.getText().toString());
                    additional = additional + 0.25;
                    addl.setText(additional.toString());
                }
            });
            addlsub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Double additional = Double.valueOf(addl.getText().toString());
                    if(additional > 0.0) {
                        additional = additional - 0.25;
                    }else{
                        additional = 0.0;
                    }
                    addl.setText(additional.toString());
                }
            });

        }
    });

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.tvname.setText(mData.get(position).getName());
    holder.tvcat.setText(mData.get(position).getCategorie());
    // load image from the internet using Glide
    Glide.with(mContext).load(mData.get(position).getImage()).apply(options).into(holder.AnimeThumbnail);





}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView tvname,tv_rate,tvcat,count;
    ImageView AnimeThumbnail,addcart;
    LinearLayout view_container;



    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowname);
        tv_rate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        tvcat = itemView.findViewById(R.id.categorie);
        AnimeThumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        view_container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ophContainer);
        addcart = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addcart);
        count = itemView.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_notifcation_textview);


    }
}

public interface AdapterCallBack{
    public void onChangeBadgeCount();
}
}
```

on Save Click i want to increase cart count but i couldn't able to do so far. please kindly suggest me what can i do to increase cart count from adapter 
[Here is a screenshot of my activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQ9sY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic approach would be to make use of interface which is what you are doing.

Below just 2 changes in your code :

Implement interface in your Main Activity not in your Fragment.

Replace with below

```
recyleradpater = new RvAdapter(getContext(), lstOphthalmic,getActivity());
```

Will work for sure.

Comment: But how to call the method in adapter ?? Just calling the nane of method ??? And what to do in this method just set the text in method in Main Activity?

Comment: I didn't get your query. Can you please tell me what exactly what you want.

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to say is. When i click save button on recyclerview item added in database and the other thing that i want is to increase cart count at that moment meaning to call that interface method here. What code should i write in that method in Main Activity just set the text in this method would be enough for me?? just like that : String count = 
    String.valueOf(mDBHelper.numberOfRows());
    tv.setText(count); . and How to call interface method in adapter?

Comment: When you get callback in your Main Activity where you have implemented interface then just you need to do, count.setText(order_count++); //here order_count  is the static variable of type int which you should declare at class level.

Comment: after implementing method. i have got null reference error !!! What to do now ? Any suggestion.

Comment: In your adapter, declare (AdapterCallBack adpatercallback;) then in adapter construction change to (this.adpatercallback = adpatercallback;) after that  in your add button on click listner make call to interface method like adpatercallback.onChangeBadgeCount(); Hope this would work.

Comment: Everything is working fine in activity but there is an error:  in this line recyleradpater = new RvAdapter(getContext(), lstOphthalmic,getActivity()); In the adapter i have write this:    public RvAdapter(Context mContext, List lst,AdapterCallBack adapter) {


        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = lst;
        options = new RequestOptions()
                .centerCrop()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
                .error(R.drawable.loading);
        this.mAdpaterCallBack = adapter;

    }

Comment: Now what parameter should i gave in the last                                     
      recyleradpater = new RvAdapter(getContext(), lstOphthalmic,getActivity());                            instead of get activity